# Планировщик cron. Бесперерывная работа php-скрипта

Tags: php, cron

Стоит задача постоянно иметь запущенный php-скрипт (или периодически его запускать с небольшим интервалом времени), для этого лучше всего подходит cron (насколько я знаю).

Проблема заключается в том, что скрипт может завершить работу в любой момент (выскакивает надпись `Terminated` либо просто "стопорится").

Как правильно организовать этот процесс?

Comment: Terminated - имеется ввиду, что он может "случайно упасть"?

Comment: сделайте вечный цикл в скрипте, типа while(true){}

Comment: Это скорее всего означает что время выполнения ограничено и он завершает работу после длительной работы. Вопрос не в этом, а в том, что иногда он без ошибок прекращает работу.

Comment: Цикл уже имеется, не вечный, но довольно длительный, поэтому и нужно держать рабочим скрипт, чтобы его завершить.

Comment: Так в чем сейчас проблема? Вы не знаете как сделать так, чтобы не запускалось несколько экземпляров задачи? Или в том, что скрипт перестает работать и вы не знаете почему?

Comment: смотря, что он делает - слушает запросы, проверяет что-то периодически...

Comment: ВОРОН, да-да, не знаю как сделать так, чтобы не вышло, что запустились несколько скриптов параллельно.

Comment: если валится из-за ошибок, делайте try/catch

Comment: while (true) { запуск скрипта и ожидание, пока он закончится }

Comment: Чтоб не запускалось паралельно - 2 варианта - запись в базе что уже запущено, и не запускать при обнаружении записи или создавать файлик и проверять его существование. В конце работы удалять (запись/файл)

Comment: @myvzar, а потом скрипт с грохотом падает и запись не удаляется. В результате ни одна задача не запущена

Comment: try/catch - и с грохотом не упадет.

Comment: @myvzar, а kill $PID? Можно, конечно, сигналы ловить, но зачем все так усложнять? А если mysql временно недоступен будет? И лучше уж тогда через set_exception_handler/set_error_handler работать, чтобы наверняка.

Answer (score 2):

Я использую в своих скриптах следующее:

```
<?php

$fname = __FILE__ . '.pid'; // Определяем название файла-флага
$item_pid = rand(1111, 9999); // Генерируем идентификатор
if (!@file_exists($fname)) { // проверяем его наличие
    file_put_contents($fname, $item_pid); // если нет - всё хорошо
} else {
    if (time() - filemtime($fname) > 30) { // если файл был обновлен более 30 секунд назад
        @touch($fname); // обновляем дату файла и продолжаем
    } else { // если файл обновлен менее 30 секунд назад, считаем, что скрипт НЕ УПАЛ
        echo "[!] PID file exists, date actual, Exit\r\n";
        exit; // и ВЫХОДИМ, чтобы не нарушать работу первой копии
    }
}
while(1) {
/*

    Какие-то действия постоянного характера [ВАШ КОД]

*/
    if (file_get_contents($fname) != $item_pid) {
        echo "[!] PID file contains invalid data, Exit\r\n";
        exit;
    } else {
        @touch($fname);
    }
}

unlink($fname); // Удаляем файл-флаг, чтобы не путать следующий запуск

?>
```

Думаю комментарии внесли ясность.

В случае постоянной работы, например цикла, нужно при итерациях делать `@touch($fname);`, иначе при выполнении действий более 30 секунд скрипт будет считать, что первая копия отвалилась с ошибкой...

**UPDATE:**
Учитывая возможность восстановления зависшего процесса добавил условие.

Comment: А если там mysql-запрос будет 31 секунду выполняться? Проще тогда уж через bash-скрипт запускать, тогда никаких изменений в коде делать не надо, все в скрипте будет.

Comment: Ну всё просто, 30 секунд - максимальное время, за которое все действия в одной итерации точно пройдут. Нет проблем рассчитать время, за которое запрос точно выполниться, применимо к комментарию выше. Учитывая отсутствие информации об архитектуре системы, считаю такой способ контроля скрипта самым простым.

Comment: Он простой, но если случилась какая-нить неприятность и мы вовремя не обновили файл, то будет запущено уже две задачи. bash-скрипт не намного сложнее (простой [пример](http://stackoverflow.com/a/185473/4041128)), но защищает от таких случайностей.

Comment: А мне этот подход понравился, хотя бы потому, что он очень простой. 
Но интересует одна вещь: что, если скрипт застопорится, то процесс будет жить или уничтожится?

Comment: Процесс будет жить. У меня таких прецедентов не было, но чтобы убивались другие процессы надо несколько изменить скрипт. Например ввести идентификатор (внутри скрипта) который будет записываться в файл-флаг. При каждой итерации проверять, что именно тот идентификатор записан в файл, если нет, то выходить... Внес изменение в код. Но это танцы с бубном!

Answer (score -1):

> для этого лучше всего подходит cron (насколько я знаю).

Нет, это заблуждение. Крон для этой задачи не подходит совсем.

Крон служит для **запуска по расписанию**. Скрипт, работающий раз в сутки в течение одной секунды не подходит под определение "постоянно работающего скрипта".
Под это определение попадает просто **постоянно работающий скрипт.** Скрипт, который **один раз запустили**, и он дальше постоянно выполняется. Такие скрипты называют *демонами*.

А попытка скрестить такой скрипт с кроном как раз и приводит к ненужным извращениям, описанным в другом ответе.